# Void error converting from double, but there is no void in my code

Tags: java

I have made some code, but now it keeps giving me an error :

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: void cannot be converted to double.*

Thing is there are no void methods in my code.

```
public double separatingcomputation(){

        startingTimeinminutes = startingTime / 100;                
        elapsedminutes = (double)startingTimeinminutes;      //Minutes captured before losing to int

        startingTimeinhours = (int) startingTimeinminutes;         //Starting hours

        endingTimeinminutes = endingTime /100;
        endingTimeinminutes = (double)endingTimeinminutes;         //Minutes captured before losing to int
        endingTimeinhours = (int) endingTimeinminutes;            //Ending hours

        elapsedminutes = ((double)elapsedminutes - startingTimeinhours ) * 100;  //Get starting the minutes
        endingTimeinminutes = ((double)endingTimeinminutes - endingTimeinhours) * 100;         //Get ending the minutes

        startingTimeinhours = (double) ((startingTimeinhours - 12) * 60 + elapsedminutes) / 60;



        return (double) startingTimeinhours ;
```

Comment: I did have  method that I set to void but realized it didn't work like that and changed it back to double.

Comment: what's the type of :
startingTimeinminutes ,
elapsedminutes ,
startingTimeinhours ,
endingTimeinminutes ?

Comment: tell me so that i can help you

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace or a line number of the error?

Comment: The code posted will compile without that error. I suggest you try cleaning your workspace and compile again.

Comment: I am just guessing here, but if you are overriding the `void` method called `separatingcomputation`, perhaps you cannot change its signature. I don't know if this is the case or if you're actually overriding, but I don't see any other reason for error.

Comment: The only real issue is the convertion from double to int when calculating `startingTimeinhours`.

Comment: Maybe you have accidentally written `public void separatingcomputation()`. @starf mentioned that the code compiles for him, so you haven't provided a [mcve]. Do that.

Comment: I erased and pasted the code again and it is working now, it seems the compiler even tho I had long erased the void method it didn't recognized that or something, thank you a  lot.

Comment: The generic Q&A for this error is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369301/what-does-incompatible-types-void-cannot-be-converted-to-mean.  But since the actual problem was most likely that the OP didn't recompile, or his IDE was out of sync, the Q should really be closed as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it was restarting the program or the fact that I copied and re-pasted the code but its not giving me the error now. whatever the case it seems to have been solved and it wasn't a major thing. thanks.